# Converting to Maven Project in Eclipse results in ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am using the m2eclipse plugin in Eclipse Juno, with JDK 1.7 (switched from JRE 1.6 based on some searches on Stack Overflow).

The bare-bones Android application runs fine when newly created.  However, when I convert it to a Maven Project, I start getting a ClassNotFoundException whenever I try to run the application.  I've tried updating the project, restarting Eclipse, checking all libraries in the build path, cleaning and rebuilding the project, restarting the emulator, and reducing my pom.xml to the bare minimum.

What is the cause of this error?  Is it some simple misconfiguration for Maven?

**My LogCat:**

```
07-09 23:07:18.027: D/AndroidRuntime(958): Shutting down VM
07-09 23:07:18.027: W/dalvikvm(958): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myproject/com.example.myproject.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.myproject.MainActivity
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.myactivity.MainActivity
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
07-09 23:07:18.137: E/AndroidRuntime(958):  ... 11 more
```

**My pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>android</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**My MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.myproject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

**Update:** I've found that trying to do Maven Clean and Maven generate-sources succeed, on the pom.xml.  However, Maven install gives me an error:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] MainActivity.java:[12,33] package R does not exist
[ERROR] MainActivity.java:[18,44] package R does not exist
```

I've also added a few things (dependency and packaging) as well as modified (1.6->1.7, 3.1->3.0) the pom.xml file in this latest edit.

Comment: JRE 1.6 was insufficient, yes, but the Oracle JDK 1.6 is the one that is officially recommended by the documentation for Android development, not the JDK 1.7. In any case, this is probably not what's causing this particular error, although it would be a good idea for you to switch back to the Oracle JDK 1.6 eventually.

Comment: That is a bit awkward situation, since Oracle recommends using 1.7 since they don't update their 1.6.  Kindof catch 22.

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBuildMaven/article.html) can help.

Comment: According to [this post from the ADT team](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/adt-dev/Bq9GO4edMpQ/9r43RwniRBoJ), JDK6 is still specified as the minimum officially but JDK7 should work fine since sometime last year.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, to avoid such situations, you shouldn't create a new project in Eclipse and then convert it to maven, but create android project with maven from scratch. In addition, always build your projects also in terminal (just in case) because m2eclipse generates errors from time to time, especially in complex projects.

Try this (in terminal):

1. Make a folder, eg. myMvnProjects.
2. Go to this folder.
3. Type: `mvn archetype:generate`
4. Choose `de.akquinet.android.archetypes:android-quickstart (Creates a skeleton for an Android application)` (or something else - it depends on your needs).
5. Provide essential parameters (platform, groupId, artifactId, version etc.)
6. Click enter (or return on Mac) and that's it - Maven generates a simple project for you.
7. Type : `mvn clean install` and wait until it builds.

BTW, I'm curious why you have `<packaging>jar</packaging>` in your main android project. You should have `<packaging>apk</packaging>`. What is more, Maven works without any problem with JDK 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just create a jar in maven and deploy it to your device, expecting to android to work, android uses a special compiler and jar compression.  something like this may help: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev.html